# Reading keystrokes of other applications

Tags: windows, macos, keyloggers

Is it possible for other application running in the OS to read the keystrokes that my application uses?

What about mouse events and window handles?

Is there any security wall that the OS uses to shield my application from other potential dangerous applications that have might infiltrated into the machine?

Is there any difference between Windows in Mac in this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Dupe of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/reading-keystrokes-of-other-applications (which is the original, migrated form StackOverflow)

Comment: There is actually a metasploit module for OSX key logging. It does not need to be run as root. The link is here: http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/osx/capture/keylog_recorder And here is the source: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/post/osx/capture/keylog_recorder.rb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh man, you're in for a treat this evening!

> Is it possible for other application running in the OS to read the keystrokes that my application uses?
>
> What about mouse events and window handles?

Absolutely. Windows message processing is really complicated. It works a bit like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{

switch ( msg )
{
case WM_CREATE:

case WM_DESTROY:

case WM_COMMAND:

case WM_KEYDOWN:
}
}
```

and so on. Basically, this function is continually called for each message the graphics system has for your app. Each different type of message is identified by `msg`, and `hwnd` gives you your window handle. The information for each type of command is stored in `wparam` and `lparam` or some combination thereof.

It turns out there are a huge number of [API Hooking Techniques](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed) in Windows. The good news is that one of them is [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to insert your own handler into another application's message pipeline and, well, steal their messages. That's everything - every button pressed, every menu, every resize, create, destroy, mouse move, redraw, keydown, keyup etc that happens on that Window.

There is another way to invite yourself in - use DLL Injection to get your code into the process' address space and then modify the running code.

None of this is easy, but it is certainly possible

Now, you wanted to know about defences. Well, [UIPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vishalsi/what-is-user-interface-privilege-isolation-uipi-on-vista), or User Interface Privilege Isolation, is one such defence. The privilege level of the process (or Mandatory Integrity Level) controls what other processes can do as that process. Vista uses this trick to isolate certain applications from each other. Next up; [Window Stations, Desktops and Sessions](https://www.brianbondy.com/blog/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops). Did you know that when you get that UAC dialog, you're actually running on a separate desktop and `consent.exe` takes a screenshot of your desktop and pastes it as the background for the new desktop?

Wait what?

Go back a bit. You can have multiple desktops per Window station and, guess what? Well:

> Windows inside the Windows OS are children of Desktop objects.

So that means if you create a separate desktop for your application to run in and crucially handles to objects in the main desktop don't show up here. Windows uses this to protect the logon, lock screens, UAC screens. It's also used by me in a product I'm developing, and it's used by [KeePass](https://keepass.info/).

These features are fundamental to Vista/Windows 7 and they're unlikely to go away. To make the most of them, leave UAC turned on and [possibly read this](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.co.uk/2007/02/running-vista-every-day.html).

Now, Mac OS X. Disclaimer: I know very little about the OS X stack; however, I am familiar with Linux/X Server. Linux is increasingly moving towards RBAC/MAC-type systems with the introduction of posix capabilities rather than setuid bits and the like. However, in implementing SELinux in X, the developers ran up against a brick wall. X basically runs its server (the desktop) as root (should be sending you warning signals) and desktop applications (clients) connect to it locally and pass in nothing more than a cookie. [See X authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization).

Fundamentally, X operates over some kind of [transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture), making your actions at least sniffable to outsiders if encryption is not used. Firstly, the Linux kernel might just give you permission to capture keystroke with [`ioperm()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ioperm). Failing that, if you have the magic cookie, you can use it to connect to the X server and run [all sorts of commands](http://www.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/securityfocus/pen-test/2001-08/0054.html). This requires a dodgy setup, of course, but it is feasible.

In terms of adding in isolation between clients and servers, [XACE](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/security/XACE-Spec.html) is the SELinux equivalent.

Now, how does this apply to Mac OS X? Well, not a lot - apparently, X11 is deprecated or something. Anyway, internally, Mac OS X uses a rendering engine of its own and its own Windowing code (Cocoa). Well, it turns out with some digging [you can intercept messages on Mac OS X too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472806/is-it-possible-to-intercept-the-image-data-of-mac-osx-screen). Cocoa is the desktop API; underneath it uses something called Quartz which [also supports taps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776567/osx-quartz-event-taps-event-types-and-how-to-edit-events)).

I am not fully versed on how this all works - however, I'm imagining it comes down to getting the appropriate privileges and just making the right calls. Mac OS X uses Unix Shared objects, so its callback mechanism will basically use function pointers. I'm not sure what privilege restrictions are there.

If anyone knows more about OS X, do feel free to take what I've said and expand on it in your own answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Generally most applications do not specifically protect keystrokes, so often a malicious application can [log all your keystrokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging).

This is why so much effort is put into patching, service releases, security updates, antivirus etc - as once a malicious application is on your machine it can do pretty much anything (in a standard window, linux or macos environment)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, they are called key-loggers. There is software out there that warns you of this behavior if it occurs (I personally use Kaspersky Internet Security).

If you are interested in how it is done, there is an example in VB about this on [hungry hackers](http://www.hungry-hackers.com/2008/05/how-to-write-a-keylogger.html).